# cannot set state inside useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, react-hooks

I'd like to set a value to `nickid` state using react hooks.

UID from database has a value, then I set the state and console.log after it, it shows null.

any ideas why?

My code:

```
const [nickid, setNickid] = useState(null); //uid

useEffect(() => {
    firebase.database().ref('/users/').orderByChild('user').equalTo(props.match.params.user).once('value').then(snapshot => {
        if (snapshot.exists()){
            var uid = Object.keys(snapshot.val())[0]; //uid has a value
            setNickid({ nickid: uid });

            console.log(nickid); // here is null
```

Comment: setNickid is async, so console.log(nickid) is the initializeState. The state is not update yet.

Answer (score 1):

**First** thing `setState/setNickid` is async function so you will not get direct that value right after it

**Second**, change this

```
setNickid({ nickid: uid });
```

To

```
setNickid(uid);
```

**[WORKING DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-react-state-effect?file=index.js)**

Answer (score 1):

setState is async function (does not execute immediately) 
if you want to console log nickid when it is changed

```
useEffect(()=>{
  console.log(nickid)
},[nickid])
```